# How to programmatically make cocoa application active

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsapplication

I've got a background process that makes a transparent window appear when a hotkey is pressed:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[[content animator] setAlphaValue:1.0]; // alpha was 0.0
```

... the window shows up fine & in front of the other windows (as I want it to), however until I manually click the window whatever application was active when the window appears remains active. I was expecting the 'makeKeyAndOrderFront' to make the application active as well, however adding a NSLog line to my -applicationWillBecomeActive shows it's not getting any active notification until the mouse click is performed.

Does anyone know how I can set my application active @ the same time I issue the -makeKeyAndOrderFront ? I need it active so that it can begin accepting keyboard input - any assistance needed :-)

Comment: Don't do this - Mac apps don't generally steal focus for good reason.

Comment: But in this case, the focus is expected to be in his app because the user has used the hotkey.

Comment: @AlBlue "generally".  Lots of great apps do things that aren't "generally" done.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Look at `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps : YES];`.

Comment: *THANK YOU !!!* - I was pulling my hair out trying stuff with NSRunningApplication's -activateWithOptions , but everything I tried resulted in a beach ball...

Answer (score 12):

For 10.6 or greater

```
[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:(NSApplicationActivateAllWindows | NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps)];
```

Comment: best place to put this? `applicationDidFinishLaunching` ?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've a multi-window app that wouldn't activate correctly unless `NSApplicationActivateAllWindows` was set.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2+** of @Arvin answer

```
NSRunningApplication.current.activate(options: [.activateIgnoringOtherApps, .activateAllWindows])
```

Comment: This helped me to find what I needed in Xamarin MacOS `NSRunningApplication.CurrentApplication.Activate(NSApplicationActivationOptions.ActivateIgnoringOtherWindows);`